# Is it possible to hide dependencies of an angular directive to the user?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-management

I am making an Angular directive that uses another module's directives (`ng-file-upload` not to mention it). For the moment, I am declaring `ng-file-upload` in my `index.html`.

In the perspective of sharing my directive, I would like to make it as handy to use as possible and thus hide the use of `ng-file-upload` for the users. With my actual organisation, users will have to add `ng-file-upload` in their scripts declaration too. This is a bit of a trouble because users should not have to bother with my directive's dependencies.

Is there a way to load my dependencies transparently for the users, just like conventional languages do?

(Sorry for my bad english. This is not my mother tongue)

Comment: Depending on the license, you could always bundle it with your own script. I don't really recommend that approach though. It isn't really that bad to force your users to install your dependencies, especially if your directive or the dependency is available through npm or similar.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "bundle" ?

It's not the installation that is an annoyance, but also the fact that they have to declare the correct `.js` file (or even the correct `.js` fileS)

Comment: Bundling is the process of combining multiple files (in this case `.js` files) into a single file before distributing them. The problem with bundling your dependencies with your module is that you enforce how your consumers should include these dependencies. They might for instance benefit from it coming from a CDN instead, or perhaps their existing application already uses the dependency, thus having it bundled with your module may result in it being included twice (thus increasing the bandwidth usage) unless they specifically exclude their own instance.

Comment: Usually this is handled by NPM dependencies. ng-file-upload should be a dependency of the package and be `require`d in script. Bundled script that is included in `dist` should not contain third party scripts.